# Mustache returns [object object] after iterating over array

Tags: javascript, arrays, mustache

Im going over a very simple case and wondering why it renders the array as

> [object object]

instead of printing strings

```
    (function(){
        var context = {
            steps: ['step1', 'step2', 'step3'],
        }
        var template = document.getElementById('template').innerHTML;
        var result = Mustache.render(template, context);
        document.getElementById('template').innerHTML = result;
    })();
```

template is:

```
                    {{#steps}}
                    <tr>
                        <td valign="top" style="width: 80px;">01.</td>
                        <td valign="top" style="width: 560px; text-align: left;">{{.}}</td>
                    </tr>
                    {{/steps}}
```

Comment: Paste More HTML code, for example, the thing who has id `template`

Comment: its working fine: http://jsfiddle.net/j4mawjv7/

Comment: template is on body element. its a simple landing page

Answer (score 0):

You can't put the template on your body element, because your mustache template isn't valid HTML. Put it in a `<script type="text/x-mustache">` tag instead to keep it from getting mangled.